# Flutter returning noSuchMethodError when checking if it is mounted

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a flutter app and it is throwing

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'markNeedsBuild' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: markNeedsBuild()
```

here is the code that throws that:

```dart
if (this.mounted) {
    setState(() {
        groupDocument = groups.documents[0];
        group = groupDocument.data;
    });
}
```

I'm checking the mounted property, since that is executed after a future ends

EDIT1:

My build method is like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
  return ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
    children: children
  );
}
```

Comment: The error is not really about triggering `NoSuchMethodError`; it's about you trying to invoke a method on `null`.  The error should have given you a stack trace.  That should give you a clue about where you're attempting that invocation.

Answer (score 0):

setState() causes a build, and your build method is likely faulty and possibly not returning a Widget.